# Porque o meu ciclo de forEach não está imprimindo nada?

Tags: java, java-8

```
public static Iterable<String> select(Iterable<String> it, Predicate<String> pred) { 
    ((Collection<String>) it).removeIf(pred);
    return it;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("a");
    list.add("");
    list.add("b");
    list.add("");
    list.add("c");
    Iterable<String> nonEmpty = select(list, s -> !s.isEmpty());
    for(String s : nonEmpty) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Eu quero através da função `select` filtrar o conteúdo (em que o filtro é dado através do `Predicate`) de um objeto que seja iterável. Tentei mexer em várias coisas, uma delas foi fazer o *cast* para utilizar o `removeIf` porém quando testo, não sai nenhuma print.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pelo que entendi seu código está removendo o que é **diferente de vazio** e deve estar imprimindo coisas em branco.

Troque para `select(list, String::isEmpty);` que irá funcionar

Answer (score 8):

O problema está neste *lambda*:

```
s -> !s.isEmpty()
```

Ele retorna `true` quando a string **não** é vazia. E o método [`removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) remove os elementos para os quais o predicado é `true`.

Ou seja, o código está removendo as strings não-vazias, e no fim só sobram as strings vazias. Você pode conferir isso se imprimir alguma coisa antes de cada elemento:

```
Iterable<String> nonEmpty = select(list, s -> !s.isEmpty());
for (String s : nonEmpty) {
    System.out.println("- " + s);
}
```

A saída é:

```
- 
-
```

Ou seja, no fim sobraram as duas strings vazias.

---

Se quer remover as strings vazias, basta retirar o `!` do *lambda*:

```
Iterable<String> nonEmpty = select(list, s -> s.isEmpty());
for (String s : nonEmpty) {
    System.out.println("- " + s);
}
```

Assim ele retorna `true` quando a string for vazia, e `removeIf` remove as strings vazias. A saída é:

```
- a
- b
- c
```

---

Mas precisa usar um `Predicate`? Você pode usar um *loop* simples se quiser:

```
for (Iterator<String> it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    if (it.next().isEmpty()) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

Ou, se quiser mesmo usar um `Predicate`, pode transformar a lista em um *stream* e filtrar as strings não vazias:

```
List<String> naoVazios = list.stream()
                             .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Nesse caso eu usei `!s.isEmpty()`, pois eu quero filtrar as strings que não são vazias.

O código acima cria outra lista, contendo somente as strings não vazias. Mas se quiser só imprimir os elementos, por exemplo, pode fazer:

```
list.stream()
    .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Ou, de maneira mais geral:

```
list.stream()
    .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
    .forEach(s -> {
    // fazer o que quiser com a String s
    });
```